# What is a minimal symbolic execution example?

Tags: formal-verification, symbolic-execution

I'd like to see a minimal [symbolic execution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145303/symbolic-execution-vs-fuzz-testing-whats-the-difference) / [formal verification](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145361/whats-the-difference-between-smt-solvers-and-formal-verification) example using the following function:

```js
function f(uint256 a) public returns(uint256){
  a = a + 1;
  return a;
}
```

What would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we look at this function, we can easily see two paths this function can take.

1. `a` < `2^256`, a = a + 1, function returns
2. `a` == `2^256`, a = a + 1 overflows, function reverts

We can turn these into a set of boolean expressions. Then, input those into a [SAT Solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver) with some "question" added to it. We can see what this code would look like in SMT-LIB format to input to something like the [z3](https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/docs/logic/intro/) SMT Solvet.

```js
; Declare a symbolic integer variable 'a' as a 256-bit integer
(declare-const a (_ BitVec 256))

; Create a context for Path 1
(push)

; Add assertions for Path 1
; assert a is not equal to `uint256.max`
(assert (distinct a #xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff))
(check-sat)

; Remove the context for Path 1
(pop)

; Create a context for Path 2
(push)

; Add assertions for Path 2
; assert a is equal to `uint256.max`
(assert (= a #xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff))
; bvult is "bit vector unsigned less than", so we are checking that a + 1 is less than a
(assert (bvult (bvadd a (_ bv1 256)) a))

; Check if Path 2 is satisfiable
(check-sat)
```

The `(check-sat)` line is sort of the "question" we are asking. We are saying "is there a variable `a` such that all the booleans in this list are true?"

If the property of our smart contract was "f should never revert" we could see Path 2 holds that "question".

This line:

```js
(assert (bvult (bvadd a (_ bv1 256)) a))
```

Is a boolean saying essentially `(a + 1 > a)`. Since we have included it, you could argue the question we are asking our theorem solver is "with these constraints, could function `f` ever revert?"

The output of this in z3 would be the following:

```
sat
```

Meaning, that yes, the function `f` could revert.

The hard part of all this, is converting your solidity -> SMT-LIB for a solver solver to digest. Tools like [manticore](https://github.com/trailofbits/manticore) can do this, but will give you the SMT-LIB for the entire contract. ChatGPT can also help create these conversions. It can be really tricky to get this conversion correct though.